# Erro in render inset box-shadow?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I have a gallery of images with inset box-shadow and depending of the window size, appear a very thin line in the border of the box. I would like to remove this line but I think that it can be a render error. I tested in chrome and safari.

Here a live of the page > https://mostrajoelzitoaraujo.com.br/

Here the image of the bug:

[screenshot of the line error in border image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOrhn.jpg)

Here the code HTML/PHP:

```
<div class="homeGaleria__img">
    <div class="homeGaleria__img-normal" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_theme_file_uri( $imgArr[$rand[0]] ) ; ?>');">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="homeGaleria__img-hover" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_theme_file_uri( $imgArrHover[$rand[0]] ) ; ?>');">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

and here the SASS

```
@mixin img-normal($color, $height) {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;

    width: 100%;
    height: $height;

    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 8px $color inset;
    border: hidden;

    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

@mixin img-filtro($color, $height) {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 8px white inset;
    border: hidden;

    width: 100%;
    height: $height;


    &::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: $color;
        mix-blend-mode: multiply;

        transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here a live of the page > https://mostrajoelzitoaraujo.com.br/